# Rails console issue with Docker compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, rails-console

I have created a rails app with a pgsql database using DockerCompose.
It seems to work fine but I have issues with using the rails console while running the app.
What I do is :

- `docker-compose up`. The app starts running.
- Then I run : `docker exec -it ID_OF_RAILS_CONTAINER bin/rails console`, or "*docker-compose run CONTAINER_NAME rails console*" (I tried both)

The console opens with this :

```
Creating transcendance_backend_run ... done
Running via Spring preloader in process 21
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Then when I try to create a model, I get the following error:

```
irb(main):001:0> rails g model user name guild_id banned
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (undefined local variable or method `banned' for main:Object)
```

Whatever I type, I get this error.

I have tried commenting "*gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'*" in my gemfile, but now the console just hangs forever when I try to generate a model.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I think `rails generate` is a shell command, not a Ruby method call.  I'd run this in your local source tree, outside of Docker, and outside an `irb` interpreter; then rebuild your image with the updated model code.

Answer (score 0):

`generate` is a Rake task bundled with Rails. You can run it in the container like this

```sh
docker exec -it ID_OF_RAILS_CONTAINER bin/rails model user name guild_id banned
```

However, unless the container file system is configured to do a two-way sync with your local, it's likely that the files generated won't appear on you local machine.